# arangodb java driver `by-example`

Tags: java, arangodb

Arango provides an http interface to performing searches *by-example*
`/_api/simple/by-example`
an example of a query being

`{ 
  "collection" : "products", 
  "example" : { 
    "i" : 1 
  } 
}`

does the [java-driver](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver) provide an interface?

Answer (score 0):

No I do not currently see this in the java driver, I think you would have to ask for that feature.

That beeing said, this API really just constructs an AQL query with a few `FILTER` statements. 
You could easily write that yourself using java reflection.

The relevant code section would be here:
https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/devel/js/server/modules/%40arangodb/simple-query.js#L107